# Connection String with Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to test a simple connection to my database with VB.NET on my SQL Server 2008. The problem is my login is with Windows Authentication mode and I enter no password for it to connect to my SQL server.

How will a connection string in this case look like? This has blocked my progress for the whole day.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim i As Integer
        connetionString = "Data Source=PEDRAM-PC\PEDRAM;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=Pedram-PC\Pedram;Password=bro"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `Integrated Security=SSPI` instead of the username and password.

Comment: ArgumentException:Keyword not supported: 'use integrated security'. I get it on connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)